# UiTableCell UIImageView - last cell not displaying image

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard, row

I have am using storyboards and have a view with a UITableView with a custom UITable cell.

The cell has a UISwitch, UILabel and a UIImageView. There are just 3 rows in the table and everything displays as it should apart from the the UIImageView in the last row.

The data is there as the UISwitch and UILabel are set correctly. The image exists and is valid as it is the same image used in the first row that displays correctly. My code for cellForRowAtIndexPath is below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"In SettingsViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath\n");

    shared_prefs = [SharedPrefs sharedInstance];
    Message *myMessage = [shared_prefs.Messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myTableCellId";  
    myTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[myTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.mainText.text = myMessage.MessageText;

    cell.mainImage.image=nil;
    [cell.mainImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myMessage.Background]];

    [cell.activeSwitch setOn:myMessage.Active];

    if (myMessage.Deletable)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is driving me made !!!

I have now checked as suggested by and yes, it does show all the images, both the first & third rows use image1 but in the 3rd row the image isn't shown. The actual output is
2014-06-26 20:52:34.664 positivity[428:70b] In SettingsViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-06-26 20:52:34.665 positivity[428:70b] In SettingsViewController numberOfRowsInSection
2014-06-26 20:52:34.666 positivity[428:70b] In SettingsViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-06-26 20:52:34.671 positivity[428:70b] Background Image is |photo_1.JPG|
2014-06-26 20:52:34.672 positivity[428:70b] In SettingsViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-06-26 20:52:34.674 positivity[428:70b] Background Image is |photo_2.JPG|
2014-06-26 20:52:34.690 positivity[428:70b] In SettingsViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath
2014-06-26 20:52:34.693 positivity[428:70b] Background Image is |photo_1.JPG|

Comment: put `NSLog(@"%@",myMessage.Background)` under `cell.mainImage.image=nil;` and above `[cell.mainImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myMessage.Background]];` Check it wether it shows all three image name or not....

Comment: Yes, it does show all the images, both the first & third rows use image1 but in the 3rd row the image isn't shown. The actual output is